# Biblatex - math symbols in bib data

Tags: biblatex

I have a `*.bib` file that contains math symbols in a title, like

```
title = {A Mode-Matching $\Sigma\Delta$}
```

When compiling this, pdftex gives errors:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.62 

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
              }
l.62
```

when processing `\printbibliography` at line 62. I'm using bibtex to grab the `*.bib` data. Removing the `$\Sigma\Delta$` from the title eliminates the errors.

The formatted output produced by pdftex is correct, but I'd like to eliminate the error messages if possible.

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
title = {A Mode-Matching {$\Sigma\Delta$}}
```

with extra level of braces.

I suspect the problem is with `\Makelowercase` in some styles. Braces guard against it.

Comment: +1 I think wrapping any math in `\(` and `\)` should work, too.